Example of morphism of stacks which satisfies lifting but is not formally smooth
I was wondering if there is a simple example of a morphism of algebraic stacks which satisfies $1$-lifting but is not formally smooth, i.e. where the 2-commutativity of the diagram really matters.
More precisely, what is a simple example of a morphism $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ of algebraic stacks with the property that for any surjection $A \to B$ of Artinian local rings and morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} A \to \mathcal{Y}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \mathcal{X}$ forming a $1$-commutative square, there is a lift $\operatorname{Spec} A \to \mathcal{X}$ in the diagram, but such that $f$ is not (formally) smooth?
